# Incorrect "interferes with login" message

Tags: support, status-completed, login

As I recall, one could create accounts on Stack Exchange sites by clicking the login with Stack Exchange button.  At present, I encounter the error "Adblock interferes with login, please disable it." message when attempting to do so.

I've reproduced this behavior in Safari after restarting with all extensions disabled.  I've no local proxies editing the pages either.

I've no evidence that this Italian ISP interferes with any pages, certainly my default Chrome browser's various blocking extensions block all the usual trackers.

Comment: dis you got solution for this issues?

Answer (score 3):

This check is kind of inherently prone to false positives, since Adblock is hard to detect by design.

However, starting with the next build we'll be a little more conservative.  Hopefully this will fix the false positive you're getting.

Comment: When is the next build due? I still can only log in with IE at work; get same message when using Mozilla engine (i.e., Firefox or Chrome, with all extensions/add-ons disabled)

Comment: Any luck yet? I won't be able to test much longer